Using Bazel in Disconnected Environment
I have hosted the bazel-central-repository and am having issues on how to use it.  I am using the new dependency model (MODULE.bazel).  I have gone down the path of using git_repository, but that does not seem to work.  How do I tell Bazel to override the https://bcr.bazel.build path with my hosted url? Do I need to also use local_repository()? And if so, what path do I use?  It seems to be user specific. Is there a deterministic way of getting the path from git_repository?
Below is my MODULE.bazel file.
# MODULE.bazel file

# Declare the module
module(name = "hello-world", version = "1.0")

# Declare the dependency
bazel_dep(name = "rules_cc", version = "0.0.10")

# Use the extension to define the repository
ext = use_extension("@rules_cc//:defs.bzl", "git_repository")

# Define the git repository
ext.git_repository(
    name = "my_repo",
    remote = "https://your-own-git-repo-url.git",
    branch = "main",
)

I am getting the following error:
ErrorImage

Does https://bazel.build/external/registry#selecting_registries help?

Add to you .bazelrc file:
common --registry=https://your.url.com
#common --registry=https://bcr.bazel.build # Comment this out if also the BCR should be used


You need raw and branch as well. FYI, the url doesn't work in a browser.
.bazelcr
common --registry=https://my.gitlab/my_group/bazel-central-registry/raw/my_branch
